# When claiming victory in 011, can one select a character other than the Chosen One or Fenrir?

Tags: 011

According to the rules, for a normal Heroic victory:

> ...you must move the Chosen One (by the normal movement methods) to
>   the building where the Organ of Eternity is located...

However, the rules later state that one can select any character when one claims victory:

> A player who declares victory can choose to move any character,
>   even one already used by another player during that Hour, or
>   which is blocked by an event of ability.

The rules for claiming a Fenrir victory are similar, except one has to move the Fenrir character to the Chosen One; the "any character" provision applies to both a heroic victory and a Fenrir victory exactly as worded.

Now, moving the Chosen One (or Fenrir) by the normal movement rules implies that that character is the one selected since normally one can only move the selected character, and it stands to reason that the right to choose any character is just to prevent the Chosen One/Fenrir from ever becoming unavailable and thus making victory impossible for that Hour.

However, it's unclear whether either of the following scenarios would be valid:

1. Claiming a Fenrir victory, selecting the Chosen One, and moving him or her to Fenrir rather than vice-versa.
2. Claiming a victory, moving an unrelated character to the victory location, then using the "swap 2 characters" tile on the Chosen One/Fenrir.

The first scenario doesn't involve Fenrir moving at all, so it doesn't seem to count as "moving Fenrir to the location of the Chosen One" by a literal interpretation of the rules.  The second scenario could count if one considers that the Chosen One/Fenrir "moves" when the swap action is played on him/her.

Of course, I may just be overthinking this.

Are these legal plays?

Answer (score 2):

I think no, in both cases.

The rulebook ([PDF](https://boardgamegeek.com/file/download/7dsmx5s1ph/RULES_USA_285X285.pdf)) specifically mentions that when declaring victory, and as quoted by you (emphasis mine):

> If you are a hero [...] you must move the Chosen One (**by the normal movement methods**) to the building where the Organ of Eternity is located
>
> If you are the incarnation of Fenrir [...] you must move **the character whose card you have in your hand** (by the normal movement methods) to the same space as the Chosen One

I think "you must move the character whose card you have in your hand" rules out a Fenrir victory by bringing the Chosen One to him instead of selecting and moving Fenrir to the Chosen One.

In your second scenario, both cases in the rules specify "by the normal movement methods" which I think precludes moving a different character to the objective and then using a special movement technique to swap two players' locations.

The clarification allowing players that are declaring victory to select any character is presumably just a way to avoid meta-gaming and players choosing specific characters only to prevent an opposition win (or heroes accidentally working themselves into a corner).

Comment: I've updated the link. Should it happen again, I got the latest rules from the Files section of the game's Board Game Geek page (https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/93194/011#files)

Comment: Also, the answer does not appear to have changed, even if the rules have been updated somewhere